# Publish Keyword, Publish button disabled

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am trying to publish "keywords" in "Category and Keywords" section, when i click on keyword, publish button is disabled. Is there any way to publish a keyword? I have added a "taxonomy" mapping in my storage file and keywords will store in database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because that you can not publish a Keyword but the Category. If you meant to say that even for Category the publish button is disable, then explore its properties and see if the Checkbox - "Publishable" is marked or not as shown below:

[image]

Comment: +1. It's an anonymous category, but I can still tell you followed good naming conventions. ;-)

Comment: I published one category and it shows success message, its going into broker database, looking into "ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS" table but i don't have my category there, how can i verify?

Answer (score 5):

As Pankaj mentioned, you cannot publish a single Keyword. On the delivery side we are only referring to taxonomies, and there is a specific reason for using that name.

A taxonomy consists of a nested hierarchy of Keywords defined in a tree structure. A Category is a general classification defining the root of a taxonomy and a Keyword defines a value within the taxonomy hierarchy.

So the Publish option is only available at Category level, and you can only publish it as a whole. When you update a single Keyword, you have to republish the entire taxonomy